# World Clock app for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, clock

I would like to replicate the default clock app in my app. Is there any way i can use the default app in my application or i should create a new one inside my app.I would be needing the world clock function in my app , What is the best method to implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First please learn what `xcode` is. Then come back and explain to me what this has to do with the `xcode IDE`.

Comment: @shaik how do you know asker's iOs version is iOs 7?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot re-use the current 'World Clock' app within your own. You are going to have to replicate this functionality yourself.

CocoaControls does have a number of open source ['clock' controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/clock) that you might find useful.